# How do I pass a variable into AWK FNR?

Tags: awk

```
#!/bin/bash

export num=50
echo $num

awk -v awk_num=$num 'FNR==2, FNR==$awknum {print $1;}' big_report > short_report
```

I have a big_report file.  The desired output is to print rows 2 to 50 in column 1 of big_report into short_report.  However, when I run above the result in short_report, includes all lines in column 1 instead of the specified rows 2-50.
I would really appreciate it if anyone could help! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
awk -v awk_num=$num 'FNR==2, FNR==awk_num {print $1}' big_report > short_report
```